# How do I use an Immutable.js List of objects in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js

I'm learning React and Typescript by writing a solitaire card game.

From the Immutable docs for `List`: Create a new immutable List containing the values of the provided collection-like. `List<T>(): List<T>`

I see lots of examples for extending `Map`, etc., but cannot find how to use a `List` of objects with Typescript.

How do I declare the type in the interface, and how do I create a list in the state?

```
import React from 'react';
import './Game.scss';

import Card from '../card/Card'

const { List } = require('immutable');

interface IState {
  deck: List<Card>; // Doesn't compile... "typeof List" does compile, but isn't typesafe?
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  readonly state = {
    deck: List<Card>() // Also doesn't compile... "List()" does compile, but isn't typesafe?
  }

  render () {
    return ...
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
TypeScript error in /Volumes/User/dev/games/spider/src/modules/game/Game.tsx(24,9):
'List' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof List'?  TS2749

  > 24 |   deck: List<Card>;
       |         ^
    25 | }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1634, the problem is that the Immutable library must be imported, not merely required.

```
import React from 'react';
import { List } from 'immutable';
import './Game.scss';

import Card from '../card/Card'

interface IState {
  deck: List<typeof Card>;
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  readonly state: IState = {
    deck: List<typeof Card>(),
  };
```

Comment: When I use this method, I then get the error: TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'List' as a type. Did you come across this?